# Getting Task not Serializable while trying commit Kafka offsets in Spark which broadcast variables

Tags: java, apache-spark, kotlin

I've written Spark jobs that reads from Kafka and [commits offsets manually](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#kafka-itself). It worked fine but since I introduced broadcast variables, I get serializable exceptions because it tries to serialize KafkaInputDStream. Here is a minimal code showing the problem (the code is written in Kotlin but I believe it'll happen in Java too):

```
fun testBroadCast(jsc: JavaStreamingContext, kafkaStream: JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, SomeSerializableEvent>>) {
    val keyPrefix = jsc.sparkContext().broadcast("EVENT:")
    kafkaStream.foreachRDD { rdd ->
        val offsetRanges = (rdd.rdd() as HasOffsetRanges).offsetRanges()
        val prefixedIds = rdd.map { "${keyPrefix.value}:$it" }.collect()
        (kafkaStream.dstream() as CanCommitOffsets).commitAsync(offsetRanges)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val jsc = JavaStreamingContext(SparkConf().setAppName("test simple prefixer").setMaster("local[*]"), Duration(5000))
    val stream = makeStreamFromSerializableEventTopic(jsc)
    testBroadCast(jsc, stream)
    jsc.start()
    jsc.awaitTermination()
}
```

If I remove `keyPreix` and put "EVENT:" in map function, It works as expected. Otherwise I get:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: Object of org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream is being serialized  possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation. This is because  the DStream object is being referred to from within the closure.  Please rewrite the RDD operation inside this DStream to avoid this.  This has been enforced to avoid bloating of Spark tasks  with unnecessary objects.
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(DStream.scala:525)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(DStream.scala:512)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(DStream.scala:512)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.writeObject(DStream.scala:512)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2287)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:93)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
>       at ir.pegahtech.tapsell.brain.engine.jobs.Test$testBroadCast$1.call(Test.kt:226)
>       at ir.pegahtech.tapsell.brain.engine.jobs.Test$testBroadCast$1.call(Test.kt)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>       at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
>       at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

How using or not using broadcast variable relates to serializing KafkaInputDStream? Spark version is 2.2.0.